# Cannot ssh to the server

Tags: ssh, server

I have a problem ssh to the server.
Here is the content of my ssh file.

Host colfax

User xxxx

IdentifyFile -------

ProxyCommand ssh -T -v -i -----@---.com

Getting the below error:

Ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host.

Comment: Have you added the public key part on the remote machine?

Comment: @minhazur: Yes I have.

Comment: You can try this steps http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you please try downloading the key from Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.

The same problem got resolved for me after downloading the key using chrome for both Windows and Linux.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I changed to Chrome and downloaded the key. It is working now. Thanks for your suggestion.